# Why gatsby concats urls from the a tag?

Tags: javascript, gatsby

My page contains a link to remote service and it looks like:

```
<a href={link} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
  <div className="appLink">{linkText}</div>
</a>
```

in case my url starts from the `https://` it opens in a new tab perfectly, but with `www.example.com` it opens a `loclahost:8000/www.example.com` why it's happening ?

I have tried to use the `Link` imported from the gatsby but it works in the same way.

Comment: Because that’s simply how relative URLs work. _“I have tried to use the Link imported from the gatsby but it works in the same way”_ - and even that did not manage to give you a clue, that you are barking up the wrong tree to begin with?

Comment: @CBroe If it's not related to gatsby why you simply didn't suggest to change tags instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not something specific to Gatsby only, it happens with all anchors (indeed, `<Link>` component ends behaving like an anchor but within React's scope). As you can see from the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a):

> **href**
>
> The URL that the hyperlink points to. Links are not restricted to HTTP-based URLs — they can use any URL scheme supported
> by browsers

If you don't add the HTTP(s) protocol, it's interpreted as you are using a relative path, so it's concatenated to the current domain. You can check for further details in this [Absolute vs relative path/links](https://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/) article.

Keep in mind that `<Link>` component is intended to be used only for internal navigation. For external navigation, you must use the standard `<a>` tag.